# YouTube Data API - Empty "items" list from Activities:list

Tags: youtube, youtube-api, youtube-data-api

I'm trying to get user activity (liking, subscribing, etc.) through YouTube's Data API. However, when I send a GET request here: [https://youtube.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/activities?part=snippet%2CcontentDetails&maxResults=25&mine=true&key=[MY](https://youtube.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/activities?part=snippet%2CcontentDetails&maxResults=25&mine=true&key=%5BMY) API KEY]

I get a 200 response but with the "items" empty:

```json
{
  "kind": "youtube#activityListResponse",
  "etag": "Gt78OtFG_qGDXWi8-LJKjdLhoCY",
  "items": [],
  "pageInfo": {
    "totalResults": 2,
    "resultsPerPage": 25
  }
}
```

I know that the account I linked it to has activity, so I'm confused by it's not returning any information. Any assistance would be appreciated.

Comment: Its working fine for me.  are you sure your authorization is corect?

Comment: "mine
boolean
This parameter can only be used in a properly [authorized request](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/guides/authentication). Set this parameter's value to true to retrieve a feed of the authenticated user's activities."
Source: https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/activities/list
OAuth seems required while you're using your API key. I'm not sure you're not using OAuth since you don't have any error in YouTube response...

Comment: I have the mine parameter set to true and I'm using OAuth 2.0 with permission for https://www.googleapis.com/auth/youtube.readonly access. The request seems to go through fine, but I'm still getting the empty items list in the response. Should I be requesting a different access type?

Comment: have you found an answer for this question, I'm facing the same issue